# Setting environment variables based on key-value pairs in a file, where some values are quoted expressions

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have made the following bash script in order to export values from a specific file named `params.env`:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done

SOURCE=$(dirname ${SOURCE})

export $(cat "${SOURCE}/../params.env" | xargs)
```

The `params.env` has the values:

```
Param1=param1
Param2="Space separated value"
```

But it successfully exports Param1 but it fails to export Param2.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If you trust your file to be safely evaluated as code, you could just run `set -a` (causing *all* defined variables to be automatically exported), and then `source params.env`.

Comment: (BTW -- are the quotes in the file format a hard requirement? This would be easier without them; `while IFS='=' read -r name value; do printf -v "$name" %s "$value"; export "$name"; done` would suffice in that case).

Comment: Yes because I use it in otder to export enviromental variables het I use them on my Symfony written php application that also run on a cli.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, consider a lowercase variable name to replace `SOURCE`. All-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; lowercase variable names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to modify shell behavior. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: I usually use this pattern `SYMFONY__var_1` for Symfony's enviromental variable. So I use convension Instead of conviguration form parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First -- if you trust your file to be safely evaluated as a shell script with your current user's privileges, this could be as simple as:

```
set -a                           # automatically export all shell variables
source "${SOURCE}/../params.env" # evaluate file as a shell script
set +a                           # turn off automatic export
```

---

Otherwise, [the answer by mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43958885/14122) is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>If you trust the input file to only contain syntactically valid shell variable assignments, consider [Charles Duffy's simpler `set -a`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43959009/45375).</sup>

Use a `while` loop that calls `export` on each name-value pair:

```
while IFS='=' read -r name value; do
  export "$name=${value//'"'/}"
done < "${SOURCE}/../params.env"
```

Note: The above simply removes *all* `"` instances in the value and therefore assumes that values only have *enclosing* double quotes, not also (escaped) *embedded* ones.

If there *are* embedded `"` instances, and they're properly escaped as `\"` :

```
while IFS='=' read -r name value; do
  # Handle double-quoted ("...") values.
  if [[ $value =~ ^\"(.*)\"$ ]]; then
    # Using `read` without `-r` removes the \ from embedded \<char> sequences.
    IFS= read value <<<"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
  # Define and export the variable.
  export "$name=$value"
done < "${SOURCE}/../params.env"
```

- Regex matching operation `[[ $value =~ ^\"(.*)\"$ ]]` matches a `"..."` value and, by virtue of enclosing everything in between (`.*`) in `(...)`, captures that in element `1` of special array variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`, in which the results of the matching operation (`=~`) are stored.
- Use of `read` without `-r` with the contents of the content of the `"..."` value read (`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`) means that *all* `\<char>` sequences inside `"..."` are replaced with just `<char>`.